# Direct Index Queries with JanusGraph

Tags: elasticsearch, gremlin, janusgraph

I wanted to try out the direct index queries to send my fuzzy match queries directly to my elasticsearch backend. However, so far I haven't been able to get this type of query to work.

Here's the query I'm trying to run:

```
g.indexQuery("displayNameMixed", "v.displayName:(ocean)").vertices()
```

Where `displayNameMixed` is the name of the index in Jansugraph and `displayName` is the node attribute in the database (and `ocean` is the word I'm searching for).

Here's the response I get running that query:

```
No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource.indexQuery() is applicable for argument types: (String, String) values: [displayNameMixed, v.displayName:(ocean)]
```

The node type I'm searching is called `JournalFixed`. In the elasticsearch cluster, the index is called `janusgraph_displaynamemixed`.

The instructions I'm working from are here: [JanusGraph Manual Page](https://docs.janusgraph.org/index-backend/direct-index-query/)

Let me know in the comments if you need anymore details about my graph model or Janusgraph installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g` is your graphtraversalsource, you should use `graph.indexQuery()` instead.

Comment: That's great, thanks for clarifying. I simply swapped `g` for my graph name. I realize this is a separate question but can I get vertex properties from this type of query?